# Play mp3 file using pjsip

Tags: java, audio, voip, javasound, pjsip

I am working on a project where I need to play audio files over VOIP channel. I am using OpenSource phone ([SFLphone](http://sflphone.org)). I would like to know how to play an MP3 audio file over VOIP channel.

Application areas: Play audio lecture through VOIP channel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the Jack Audio Server for this purpose. Though, notice: This site is about programming. maybe this question is a little offtopic. Maybe you should try to make it on some other Stack Exchange site. If it doesn't apply to any other, then let it here.

Comment: I want to make a multiplexed (two channels - one real voice and one mp3) version of rtp channel in that one of the audio channel is hidden. Is it possible to do that in Java?

Comment: I added some relevant tags to your question so it becomes more visible in the site.